# Python Dictionary Returning Syntax Error, Unable to identify mistake

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error

I've created multiple dict and I'm now getting a syntax error for the last dictionary. I've gone through the dict but I'm unable to find the mistake. I have 10 other dict which follow a similar format but have not shown any error when printing.

This is the dict in the class: 'c_equipment'

```
    c_Equipment = {
    1:
    {
        "Chain mail":"While wearing armour you have a disadvantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks",
        "Greataxe",
        "Javelins":3,
        "Backpack", 
        "Blanket", 
        "Tinderbox", 
        "Rations": 2, 
        "Waterskin"
    },

    2:
    {
        "Chain mail",
        "Shield",
        'Warhammer',
        'Holy Symbol',
        'Backpack',
        'Crowbar',
        'Hammer',
        "Pistons":10,
        "Torches":10, 
        "Tinderbox", 
        "Ration":10, 
        'Waterskin',
        "Hempen Rope": 50, 
        "Masons Tools",
        "Dagger",
        "Playing Cards",
        "Common Clothes",
        "Pouch",
        "Rank-Insignia-(Sergeant)"
    }
    }
```

This is the initial error:

```
PS C:\Users\3com\Python> python test.py

File "test.py", line 5
"Greataxe",
          ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried commenting out the line but was still shown an error further down.

```
PS C:\Users\3com\Python> python test.py

File "test.py", line 28
"Hempen Rope":50,
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was only able to get the dict to print by commenting out most lines. I believe the error could possibly be related to the keys which have a number as a value. But I didn't encounter a problem with other dicts with the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries always have to have both keys and values. In your case there are many members that only has keys and no corresponding value.

On the other hand, curly braces with only keys are called set, and is a different object in python.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is not legal; a dict consists of `key: value` pairs.  Many of your given entries have only one.  Perhaps you want something like

```
c_Equipment = {
1:
{
    "Chain mail":"While wearing armour you have a disadvantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks",
    "Greataxe": 1,
    "Javelins":3,
    "Backpack": 1, 
    "Blanket": 1, 
    "Tinderbox": 1, 
    "Rations": 2, 
    "Waterskin": 1
},
```

Yes, you must do this for every dict element.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your dictionary:

```
"Greataxe",
"Javelins":3,
```

There is no value for the key "Greataxe".
Each entry in a dictionary has to be a `key: value` pair, and each is then separated by a comma.
So, you need to match each and every one of these key: value pairs.

In your second part (with the key `2`), you also have many missing values.